# Jquery validate submit form only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

**HTML**

```
<form class="form" name="request_more_details" class="new_leads_form_data" action="http://pr.com:3000/leads" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

    <label class="ghost-text" for="primary_lead_name">Full Name</label>
    <input maxlength="50" class="form-control fullName" placeholder="Full Name" title="Full Name" id="primary_lead_name" type="text" name="leads_form_data[name]">

    <label class="ghost-text" for="primary_lead_email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control email" placeholder="Email" title="Email" id="primary_lead_email" type="email" name="leads_form_data[email]">

    <label class="ghost-text" for="primary_lead_phone">Phone </label>
    <input class="form-control phone" placeholder="Phone " title="Phone" id="primary_lead_phone" type="tel" name="leads_form_data[phone]" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">

    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Contact Agent" class="submit btn btn-block btn-primary margin-bottom lead-form-submit" id="primary_lead_submit">

</form>
```

Below is my Javascript function.

```
$('.form').validate({
            debug: true,
            // custom function for keyup event
            onkeyup: function(element) {
              var modifiedClass = 'modified';
              var $parent = $(element).parent();
              if ($(element).val()) {
                $parent.addClass(modifiedClass);
              } else {
                $parent.removeClass(modifiedClass);
              }
            },
            rules: {
                "leads_form_data[email]": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    pattern:/^.+@.+\..+$/
                },
                "leads_form_data[phone]": {
                    required: isPhoneRequired(),
                    phoneUS: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "leads_form_data[name]": "Please enter your full name",
                "leads_form_data[email]": {
                    required: "Please enter your email",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email",
                    pattern: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                "leads_form_data[phone]": {
                    required: "Please enter your phone number",
                    phoneUS: "Please enter a valid phone number"
                },

            },
            // error handling
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {       
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                //Handling ajax call             
           }).settings.ignore = ':not(select:hidden, input:visible, textarea:visible)';
    };
```

After entering data in the field on clicking on Submit button SubmitHandler Callback is not fired.

At second time clicking on Submit button The SubmitHandler callback is hit and the functionality works.

Comment: post html code form

Comment: @bRIMOs Updated with HTML Form

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `debug: true` will always prevent the form from submitting, so the code you posted does not make sense for the problem you describe.

Secondly, are you wrapping `.validate()` in a `click` handler?  If so, that totally explains the problem.  The `.validate()` method is only used to *initialize* the plugin and should not be wrapped in a `click` handler.  Otherwise, the first click initializes the plugin, and the second click behaves normally.

Comment: No the validate is not wrapped under click event. debug:true option is set as per requirement. I will make an ajax call to submit the form details(so no need of form submission). But on first click it is not entering the submitHandler itself even though the form is valid.

Comment: @Praveenkumar, how many forms are you validating with that class?

Comment: There is only one form is validated.

Comment: @Praveenkumar, please construct a jsFiddle demo of your problem.  I see nothing in your code that would force two clicks.

Comment: @Praveenkumar, also check your console for errors.  Your brackets are not correct at the end of `.validate({ ... })`, and `ignore` can be placed inside `.validate()`.